# How to automatically select a drop down based on the condition in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

I have a drop down and by default no value is selected.In my home page I have a condition to check the query params and based on that condition it should automatically select the drop down. I've tried few ways but didn't worked. Below is the code:

**home.html:**

```
<div class="col-md-3">
<select (change) = "onAccountTypeSelection()" required="required" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="accountType">
  <option value="" selected>Select Account Type</option>
  <option *ngFor="let account of accountTypes" [value]="account.id">{{account.name}}</option>
</select>
</div>
```

**home.js:**

```
private accountTypes = Array<KeyValuePair>();
public ngOnInit() {
this.accountTypes = Array<KeyValuePair>();
this.accountTypes.push(new KeyValuePair('Saving', 'Saving'));
this.accountTypes.push(new KeyValuePair('Checking', 'Checking'));
this.accountType = '';
this.route.queryParams.subscribe((params: Params) => {
    console.log("iN HOME",params['account'],this.accountTypes[1]);
    if( params['account'] ){
        console.log("---Inside account type1",this.accountTypes);
        if(params['account'] == "saving"){
          this.accountTypes = this.accountTypes[0].id;//didnt work
        }
        else if(params['account'] == "checking"){
          this.accountTypes = this.accountTypes[1].id;//didnt work
        }
    }
 }
```

}

can someone help how I can automatically select the drop here based on params['account'] ..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I am using this method in angular  Js might be helpful to you. Just point out ng-model which you want to be selected and use this selection menu it will work definately. In your method i also got trouble but this is worked for mr try this.

`<select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedProviderList" ng-options="data.provider_id as data.doctor_name for data in DataArray">`

Answer (score -1):

**Try This :-**

```
<div class="col-md-3">
<select (change) = "onAccountTypeSelection()" required="required" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="accountType">
<option value="" selected>Select Account Type</option>
<option *ngFor="let account of accountTypes" *ngIf="toBeSelected == account.name" [value]="account.id">{{account.name}}</option>
</select>
</div>

------------------------------------------- 

 private accountTypes = Array<KeyValuePair>();
 private toBeSelected= null;
 public ngOnInit() {
        this.accountTypes = Array<KeyValuePair>();
        this.accountTypes.push(new KeyValuePair('Saving', 'Saving'));
        this.accountTypes.push(new KeyValuePair('Checking', 'Checking'));
        this.accountType = '';
        this.route.queryParams.subscribe((params: Params) => {

        console.log("iN HOME",params['account'],this.accountTypes[1]);

        if( params['account'] ){
        console.log("---Inside account type1",this.accountTypes);
        if(params['account'] == "saving"){
            this.toBeSelected = "saving";
        }
        else if(params['account'] == "checking"){
            this.toBeSelected = "checking";
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: It will throw `Can't have multiple template bindings on one element. ` error